# How do I calculate if a line on a graph is generally far away from another line?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

> **disclaimer**: I'm (evidently) not a mathematician/statistician and a total *n00b* so if this question is too basic for the community let me know! Also excuse any misuse of terminology!

Say I have two lines on a graph:

[image]

Visually I can see that *generally* the grey line is lower than the red line. But how can I say this mathematically so that it results in a true or false?

### Standard Deviation

If I apply standard deviation on the red line I can easily see if any points in the grey bar deviate from the range of the red.

But how can I say that this generally happens for all the points?

Is it about taking the average value of the grey line and seeing if that average value is within or outside the standard deviation of the red line?

Comment: In your example there is no need to take any sort of aggregate number. At every point the red line is at least as high as the grey line.

Comment: Hey Matt, that's true for this example because we can clearly see it. But how can I express it mathematically? Without looking at the graph? Or what if the line was closer and had different points on either side of the red line. How could I use maths to say, yep generally this line does or does not deviate AND it deviates higher or lower, know what I mean?

Comment: To answer the first question, say $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i$ where $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ are the red points and the $y_i$ are the grey points. If you don't have that relationship then your question starts to get vague. Perhaps you should specify  more precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: I did something similar when calibrating sensors (I wanted the lines to converge and check that they had) .. So things I looked at was the distribution of the differences (I tried a bunch of metrics) and basically scored on the distribution. So in a simplistic view I would look at differences and work out the proportion above and below zero. So if one line is always above another then I  is100% but if It was always below then it is 0%.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose ratio of MRR/Customer Churns as function of time is a good enough parameter for comparisons.